# IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb in Android Studio v2.3

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-2.3

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb
```

[image]

I installed android studio v2.3 and it won't let me run my app saying the error.
I searched online and said to click the  `Launch Standalone Sdk manager` but I am unable to locate it.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I also encountered this problem, when I tried to move an Android project from one computer to another. Since I have Android Studio 2.3 I don't have the option to run the standalone SDK-manager (or at least, I don't see any button).

On this website
http://m.blog.csdn.net/article/details?id=51204114
I found the solution to resolve the problem.

Go to **Tools >> Android >> SDK-Manager >> SDK-Tools**
Uncheck "**Android SDK Platform-Tools**" and press Apply to uninstall it again.
[image: Uninstall Android SDK Platform-Tools]
Then check it again to re-install it. Then I was able to compile my project again.

Answer (score 7):

On my system Avast Antivirus kept quarantining 'adb.exe', so the file would effectively disappear. Once I suspected that, it was simply (in Avast):

> Protection > Virus Chest > [three dot menu by the file] > Restore and add exception

If I would change a folder name, or re-install, I would have to do it again, but at least I knew where to look.

Comment: I had Avast Anti Virus for a while..this problem only started today for me!

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue, took a while to figure out but I did manage to solve it.

I ended up copying **adb.exe** from the **AppData/Local/Android/Android-SDK/Platform-Tools** folder and copied it to **AppData/Local/Android/SDK/Platform-Tools**

Seemed to work! Good luck!

Comment: @Prasad - That's a different issue. Assuming your using Windows 10. Google how to get permission... I found that I changed the folder properties from Read Only and then restarted my computer.

Comment: i done that using adminstrator login I copied. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem one day ago by deleting a file that avast notified as a virus, you can try the following steps, it works for me:

1. You have to download the "SDK Platform-Tools for your OS" at this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html
2. Unzip the downloaded package
3. Open the unzipped folder, then copy the "platform-tools" folder
4. Close Android Studio
5. Rename the existing "platform-tools" and then paste the new "platform-tools" to your sdk location, in my case: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
6. Launch Android Studio and try to run your project

You should be good to go!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Download SDK platform_tools  copy this in that where you SDK installed location. Then open android studio go to tools → sdk Manager → sdk tool → here install updated SDK platform_tools. This will surely solve the problem of the `adb.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me as well. 
Try uninstalling and reinstalling SDK platform tools in the SDK manager located in Tools>>Android>>SDK Manager.
If this doesn't work(It usually does), then it is possible that for some reason your android-sdk folder doesn't have the Platform-Tools folder containing the adb.exe file.
Go to the ADT unzipped file from the first installation and just copy it to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I had reason to reinstall Android Studio, additional folders were created sdk.
Go to **Tools >> Android >> SDK-Manager >>Android SDK NLocation** and select another folder sdk. if it is on the list.

[[image]][2]

and "ok" >> "Next">>"Next" >>"Finish"

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here - for me the solution was to completely delete my current SDK and install it again.
In addition, my antivirus detected the adb as a risky file so after reinstalling the SDK I had to make sure that my antivirus will not do it again.  
**LiooRyuuguu** answer is good but for some reason - reinstalling the SDK from the android studio tools as he suggested didn't work for me, what worked for me as I said was to detect the SDK location in my pc, delete it and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was *missing* or *corrupt* of  **adb.exe** file in this path:
***D:\Android_Sdk\sdk\platform-tools***
I manually copy the adb.exe file from some where in this SDK path and it start working.
[Image representation of adb.exe path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hlnU.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to uninstall platform-tools through the GUI, it hanged, so instead, I:

1. uninstalled **platform-tools** by deleting **`<AndroidSDK>/platform-tools`**
2. reinstalled **platform-tools** by:

   1. checking **`IntelliJ IDEA > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Android SDK Platform-Tools`**
   2. then pressing **OK**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, you can try some things like:

you install the avast antivirus

if that is not the problem then:

You have to download the ADB.EXE again via the page
and download according to your operating system

then copy the ADB.exe from that downloaded file

```
C:> Users> name> Downloads> platform-tools
```

-and copy it on the path where you have the platform-tools of your android Studio
in my case it is:

`C:> Users> name> AppData> Local> Android> sdk> platform-tools`

and that's all I hope to help you, regards :)

Answer (score -1):

After to uninstall some tools as some answers recomend, I update Android SDK Tools to Version 24.0.2 and resolved this Issue.