# IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when I run the app there is an error. The error is this -> IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb How resolve? (ps: its not a duplicate and if it is, how solve?)

Comment: restart adb please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb in Android Studio v2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778344/illegalargumentexception-unable-to-locate-adb-in-android-studio-v2-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to be using AVG antivirus? If so, then check the AVG virus chest to see if adb.exe is included. If so, then restoring it may fix your issue.

If this isn't the issue, then you can check the Android Studio SDK manager. 
In Android Studio try:
[Tools]-> [Android] -> [SDK Manager] -> [Launch Standalone Sdk Manager]

Here you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the Android SDK platform-tools.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your antivirus blocking the adb. If you can look under your antivirus vault or in my case(AVG) quarantine you might find it there.

The solution might be to delete the contents of the platform-tools and then reinstall the platform tools from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to it:-

1-Remove the platform-tools folder from the android-sdk folder and install it again from the android studio->sdk manager->click on android platform sdk tools and install it again. Also check your antivirus and check whether the file adb.exe is showing as a virus or not if showing as a virus then add the adb.exe to whitelist. And the issue will be solved.

2-If after performing the above solution still it shows unable to locate adb then do :-
For each project you need to go to file->Project Structure->Project Settings->Project->Project SDK and there you will see by default "NoSDK" is set. So you click on it and see the options select that api which is same of the virtual api device you selected as an emulator. After selecting click on ok. Now run your virtual device and you will now not see that unable to locate adb issue any further.

Thank you.